using WHERE with multiple joins is giving syntax error
I have a syntax error when using WHERE function with multiple JOINS. Im sure this is a very basic/fundamental and easy fix, but Ive tried a few things and get similar syntax error each time
SELECT AVG(s.salary) AS 'average salary'
      ,d.dept_name
  FROM salaries AS s WHERE e.gender='F' 
     JOIN employees AS e ON s.emp_no=e.emp_no JOIN dept_emp as d_e ON d_e.emp_no=e.emp_no JOIN departments as d ON
    d.dept_no = d_e.dept_no
    group
    by
    d.dept_name

tried moving the WHERE to end but same error

JOINs alwas go before WHEREs,, and GROUP BY goes at the end. That's the error.

Which dbms are you using? (Using a string literal for column alias isn't valid ANSI/ISO SQL.)

BTW, JOIN's are a part of the FROM clause. I.e. comes before WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY etc clauses.

Your where condition should come after the joins and before your grouping like so:
SELECT AVG(s.salary) AS 'average salary'
      , d.dept_name
FROM salaries AS s 
JOIN employees AS e 
    ON s.emp_no=e.emp_no 
JOIN dept_emp as d_e 
    ON d_e.emp_no=e.emp_no
JOIN departments as d 
    ON d.dept_no = d_e.dept_no
WHERE e.gender='F' 
GROUP BY d.dept_name


amazing, thanks. works now!

@Darren123456789 Please consider marking as approved if this answers your question.
